# Verifying a method call with default parameter

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

Suppose, I have a method that takes a default parameter:

```
trait Client {
   def foo(data: String, unneededStuff: String = null): String
}

class Foo(client: Client) {
  def doStuff(data: String) = client.foo(data)
}
```

Making a unit test for `Foo`, I want to verify that it calls client exactly once, and doesn't do anything else with it:

```
class FooSpec extends FunSpec with MockitoSugar {
  describe("Foo") {
    it("calls client once") {
      val client = mock[Client]
      when(client.foo(any, any)).thenReturn("bar")
      new Foo(client).doStuff("baz") shouldBe "bar"
      Mockito.verify(client).foo("baz", null)
      Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(client)
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work, because the default parameter on `Client.foo` is implemented as another method call on `Client`, so `verifyNoMoreInteractions` fails.

I can work around this by passing `null` explicitly into the `client.foo` call in `Foo`, but that kinda defeats the point of having default parameters at all - I can never have them as long as I care about testing stuff :(

I was wondering if anyone has an idea of a better work around? I am willing to do tricks in the test code, but am avert to making the production code to weird things with the sole purpose of accommodating the tests.